# Particle moving along intersection of an elliptic paraboloid and a plane

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> A particle moves along the intersection of the elliptic paraboloid $z = x^2 + 2y^2$  and the plane $x = 2$. At the moment when the particle is at $(2, 1, 5)$, what is the rate of change of $z$ with respect to $y$?

**Attempt**: This question confuses me. I thought of using the directional derivative, but since they are asking just for the rate of change with respect to $y$ only I suppose taking a simple partial derivative of $z$ with respect to $y$ is sufficient:
$$z=f(x,y),\;f_y=4y$$
$$f_y(2,1,5)=4$$

So thats the rate of change of $z$ with respect to $y$ at $(2,1,5)$. However, it is suspiciously easy and I think I am doing it wrong. Help please.

Comment: $+1$ for the great way of asking the question.

Comment: I don't understand this. $(2,1,5)$ doesn't lie on $z = x^2 + 2y^2$.

Comment: I presume you mean (2, 1, 6), right?  But yes, you're doing this correctly.  It really is that easy.

Comment: It is from a sample exam and there is no mistake in the point coordinates. (Typo?). The extraneous material about the intersection confused me a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, what you have done is correct. Note that the particle moves along the intersection of the elliptic paraboloid $z=x^2+2y^2$ and the plane $x=2$. Hence, it is actually moving along a parabola given by $z = 2y^2 + 4$. Hence, the rate of change of $z$ with respect to $y$ can be obtained directly by differentiating $z$ with respect to $y$.

The only thing is as David pointed out in his comment, the particle should be at $(2,1,6)$ and $(2,1,5)$.